# Maven clean install spring boot module runs webapp

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

When I run `mvn clean install` for my Maven module which is a spring boot application it kinda starts the spring boot web app withing the build process (and fails because of several errors)

**This is my pom for that module:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.application.coma</groupId>
        <artifactId>coma-modules</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-foo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dockerHost>http://localhost:2376</dockerHost>
                    <imageName>module-foo</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>.</dockerDirectory>
                    <imageTags>
                        <imageTag>${version}</imageTag>
                        <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
                    </imageTags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What can I do - so it won't run the web app on every build?

**Here is the parent pom for completeness:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>coma-platform</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.application.coma</groupId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>coma-modules</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>module-foo</module>
        <module>module-bar</module>
        <module>module-findandreplace</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.application.coma</groupId>
            <artifactId>coma-shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JSP relevant dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generatedSourcesDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/
                    </generatedSourcesDirectory>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>
                            com.application.coma.shared.annotation.ComaModuleAnnotationProcessor
                        </annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you happen to have any tests in your application that use `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: gonna check this tomorrow! thx for the advice. If yes - is it that it runs a context to it can do some integration tests?

Comment: Right, I believe `@SpringBootTest` will start a Spring application context. When you run `mvn install` it's also runs various other phases, in particular `test` and `verify`. So my thought is, if you have any unit or integration tests that rely on `@SpringBootTest`, Spring is going to boot up when you run `mvn install`.

Comment: I would suggest to use `mvn clean package` instead of `mvn clean install`. Apart from that your parent defines the behaviour.. And the default behaviour of the spring-boot-maven-plugin is not to start the Spring Boot App. This could be done usually by using `mvn spring-boot:run` ...

Comment: @xetra11 Did you ended up getting this resolved?

Comment: yea the test thingie solved it!